# Сокращенная запись анонимных функций Scala

Tags: scala, лямбда-выражение

Изучая Scala нарвался на отличную возможность сократить запись анонимных функций, к примеру:

`List(2,3,1).sortWith(_ < _)` вместо `List(2,3,1).sortWith((a,b) => a < b)`

Не могу найти аналог для одного аргумента, например:

`List(2,3,1).map(_) //Вызовет ошибку компиляции` вместо `List(2,3,1).map((a) => a)`

Понимаю,что это не самая важная штука в Скала, но можно ли как-то записать такую функцию в сокращенном виде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция, которая возвращает свой аргумент, называется [Тождественное отображение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Такая функция есть в Scala - это [identity](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#identity[A](x:A):A). Но сокращенной записи для неё нет.

```
scala> List(1,2,3).map(identity)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Тем не менее выглядит довольно приятно. Спасибо за ответ. `List(1,2,3) map identity` - Вот вообще без скобочек обошлись